# React.js: How to run window.open() multiple times in succession?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use a few state variables to determine which sites should be opened in new tabs (or maybe a new window if tabs aren't possible) with a single button click. However, window.open() only opens the first link.

In this code I tried pushing the target sites to an array and running .forEach and .map on the array items.

```
open_selected_websites() {
    const sites_to_open = [];

    // check each property for true and array.push if so
    this.final_social_media_site_selections.facebook && sites_to_open.push('http://facebook.com');
    this.final_social_media_site_selections.twitter && sites_to_open.push('http://twitter.com');
    this.final_social_media_site_selections.linkedin && sites_to_open.push('http://linkedin.com');
    this.final_social_media_site_selections.instagram && sites_to_open.push('http://instagram.com');
    this.final_social_media_site_selections.pinterest && sites_to_open.push('http://pinterest.com');

    console.log(sites_to_open); // all observables are true and all sites appear in the array.

    sites_to_open.forEach((social_media_site) => {
        // setTimeout(() => {
            window.open(social_media_site);
        // }, 500)
    })
```

In both cases, facebook loaded in a new tab. It is the first array item.

Then I tried adding a setTimeout to see if some time space might affect things. No, still only Facebook.

Then I tried testing only one site in each function:

```
<Button
    size='huge'
    color='orange'
    onClick={ () => {
        // final_edits_store.open_selected_websites();
        final_edits_store.test_to_open_twitter();
        final_edits_store.test_to_open_facebook();

    } }
>
    Copy Text and Open Social Media Sites in New Tabs
</Button>
```

In this case Twitter opened. The twitter function was listed first.

Does anyone know what is causing window.open() not to fire multiple times? And how to overcome this limit?

Comment: I will test this now. But in that case, why are the other sites not "taking over" the window? Only the first site loads at all.

Comment: Just added string arguments for the name parameter of each method invocation. Behavior is exactly as before: facebook opens, others are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Browsers only allow a single window to be triggered from a given user interaction.

This is a security feature to prevent websites bombing the user with vast numbers of new windows.

Comment: Are you sure? I was able to open two windows. https://jsfiddle.net/523bLxf4/4 (PS: Sorry it opens two tabs automatically)

Comment: @xadhix — When I test that code, it opens none (because you aren't triggering it from any user event).

Comment: Please check your popup blocker

Comment: @xadhix — That is just the standard behaviour of Chrome.

Comment: I moved the window.open to an onClick handler. Still works. See this - https://jsfiddle.net/523bLxf4/12/

Do you have a jsFiddle where it doesn't work?

Comment: @xadhix — when I click the button on your example, it opens Facebook and only Facebook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177992/discussion-between-xadhix-and-quentin).

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle here - [https://jsfiddle.net/523bLxf4/12/](http://JSFiddle)

Try the `name` parameter that `window.open` takes. I was able to open multiple windows.

Instead of `window.open(social_media_site);` try `window.open(social_media_site, social_media_site);`

In the `name` parameter use some tag that uniquely identifies the window.

Comment: Darn, tried it but it didn't work. I'm using Chrome 68. `        sites_to_open.forEach((social_media_site) => {
                window.open(social_media_site, social_media_site);
        })`

Comment: @SeanDezoysa Updated fiddle

Comment: @SeanDezoysa Do you have jsFiddle where it doesn't work? works in mine. Even on Button click - https://jsfiddle.net/523bLxf4/12/

Comment: I don't. I tried your code and it only opened Facebook. "Popup blocked" was displayed though, and it said twitter.com was the blocked destination. So now I'll look into that.